# HTML Decrease row spacing and column width

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. I created the following form:

```css
.input-block {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.input-block span { 
    font-size: 19px;
}

.input-block table {
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.input-block td {
    width: 10%
}

.input-block input, select {
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.input-block input, select {
  padding: 6px 6px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-block">
    <h2>Account information</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Voornaam</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="Alexander" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Tussenvoegsel</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="van" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Achternaam</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="Dijk" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Email</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="alexandervdijk@gmail.com" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="input-block">
    <h2>Wachtwoord veranderen</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Nieuw wachtwoord</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Herhaal wachtwoord</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="input-block">
    <h2>Profiel informatie</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Geslacht</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="geslacht" name="geslacht">
                    <option value="man" selected>Man</option>
                    <option value="vrouw">Vrouw</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Nationaliteit</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="nationaliteit" name="nationaliteit">
                    <option value="nederland" selected>Nederland</option>
                    <option value="belgie">Belgie</option>
                    <option value="duitsland">Duitsland</option>
                    <option value="frankrijk">Frankrijk</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now, this is almost like the way I want, but I can't change 2 things:

- I want to decrease the row spacing in the table, so the items are more compact on the screen. The space doesn't need to be gone, but a bit smaller
- The `input` boxes and the names before the input boxes can be closer to each other. I already tried to set a width of 10% on the `td` in the `table`, but that didn't work.

Can someone help me change the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adjusted your code a bit, mostly just the CSS.

Are you looking for something that's more like this?

I put a set width on your input

```
.input-block input, select {
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

and decreased width of your input block

```
.input-block {
    width: 70%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```css
.input-block {
    width: 70%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.input-block span { 
    font-size: 19px;
}

.input-block table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.input-block td {
    width: 10%;
}

.input-block input, select {
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.input-block input, select {
  padding: 6px 6px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-block">
    <h2>Account information</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Voornaam</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="Alexander" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Tussenvoegsel</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="van" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Achternaam</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="Dijk" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Email</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="alexandervdijk@gmail.com" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```